# Как вывести мой список повторно?

Tags: c, list, односвязный-список

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct t_list{
        int hour;
        int minute;
        struct t_list *next;
}t_list;
t_list *create_node(int set_hour, int set_minute){
    t_list *node=(t_list *)malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    node->hour=set_hour;
    node->minute=set_minute;
    node->next=NULL;
    return node;
}
void push_front(t_list **list, int set_hour,int set_minute){
    t_list *new_element=create_node(set_hour, set_minute);
    new_element -> next = *list;
    *list=new_element;
    t_list* head = create_node(1, 2);
}
int main() {
    t_list *list = create_node(1,3);
    push_front(&list, 3, 11);
    push_front(&list, 31, 13);
    push_front(&list, 32, 11);
    push_front(&list, 3, 11);
    while (list!=NULL){
        printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n", list->hour, list->minute);
        list=list->next;
    }
    while (list!=NULL){
        printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n", list->hour, list->minute);
        list=list->next;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Когда я пытаюсь вывести второй раз список, он не выводится, так как я уже в конце списка, как мне вернутся в начало моего односвязного списка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранять указатель на начало списка неизменным, использовать и менять его копию... :)

```
push_front(&list, 3, 11);
push_front(&list, 31, 13);
push_front(&list, 32, 11);
push_front(&list, 3, 11);
for(t_list*t = list; t; t = t->next) printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n",t->hour, t->minute);
for(t_list*t = list; t; t = t->next) printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n",t->hour, t->minute);
return 0;
```

Для тех, кто в танке:

```
t_list*t = list;
while(t) {
    printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n",t->hour, t->minute);
    t = t->next;
}
t = list;
while(t) {
    printf("hour = %d, minute=%d\n",t->hour, t->minute);
    t = t->next;
}
```

Comment: А чтобы через while работало?

Comment: Вы меня просто удивляете... Неужели непонятно? Ну ладно, смотрите...